# failed to create shim: OCI runtime while using flask in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
# Pull node docker image
FROM python:3.7-buster

RUN mkdir -p /home/deployment && chown -R root:root /home/deployment

WORKDIR /home/deployment

COPY weldTrace-linux ./
COPY verified.json ./
COPY flaskapp ./
```

My `docker-compose.yml`

```
    version: "1.0"
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.4.14
    command: mongod --port 27018
    ports:
      - 27018:27018
    volumes:
      - ${DBPATH}:/data/db
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: ./app-linux
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    volumes:
      - ${MEDIAPATH}:/data/media
  flask:
    image: python:3.7-buster
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    # volumes:
    #   - ${PIPPATH}:/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
    #   - ./flaskapp:/home/deployment/flaskapp
    # working_dir: /home/deployment/flaskapp
    command: flask run
  #   depends_on:
  #     - requirements
  # requirements:
  #   image: python:3.7-buster
  #   volumes:
  #     - ${PIPPATH}:/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
  #     - .:/home/deployment/flaskapp
  #   working_dir: /home/deployment/flaskapp
  #   command: pip install -r requirements.txt
volumes:
  data:
    external: true
  pip37:
    external: true
```

and my `PIPPATH=D:\Programming\pip37`

When I execute `docker-compose up`, I end up getting the following error

> Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create
> failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused:
> exec: "flask": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Any idea/suggestion about how to fix this? Since Dockerfile base in mongo I could not use RUN command to install any python, pip and its packages.

Comment: That seems like a rather unusual Compose setup.  Why build your Python application image `FROM mongo`, a database server?  Why overwrite the image's "system" `site-packages` directory with a volume mount?  Could you rewrite this in a single self-contained image and a single Compose container, without any of the `volumes:`, `working_dir:`, `image:`, `command:` Compose overrides?

Comment: Let me update my complete docker-compose file first, I am using multiple services in it.

Comment: Actually I am using running a node app with is converted to binary using https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg this runs without node, so I kept mongo as base

Comment: @DavidMaze Updated the question with latest docker-compose configurations

Comment: You're trying to run `flask run` in a container started from a clean `python:3.7` image, which does not know about flask unless you tell it to

Answer (score 1):

Like others have pointed out, the `python:3.7-buster` image doesn't come with `flask` installed. So `flask` needs to be installed before the `flask run` command is executed. For the setup you have, this can be done in one of two ways:

**Option 1:**

As the base image in the `Dockerfile` is also `python:3.7-buster`, an instruction can be added to install `flask`, like Kesha suggested. A slimmed down/customized version of the `Dockerfile` below:

```
FROM python:3.7-buster

RUN mkdir -p /home/deployment && chown -R root:root /home/deployment
RUN pip install flask

WORKDIR /home/deployment

COPY app.py ./
```

Then in the `docker-compose.yml`, the image built for service `web` can be reused for service `flask`. Slimmed down compose file below:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: flaskapp:latest
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: echo "Service 'web' exiting.."
  flask:
    image: flaskapp:latest
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    command: flask run --host=0.0.0.0
    depends_on:
      - web
```

The `flask run` command executes without any errors because `flask` has already been installed into the custom docker image

**Option 2:**

Continue using `python:3.7-buster` as the image for service `flask`. In that case, after starting the service, the `pip install flask` command needs to be executed before the `flask run` command. Modified compose file below:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: flaskapp:latest
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: echo "Service 'web' exiting.."
  flask:
    image: python:3.7-buster
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - ./app.py:/home/deployment/app.py
    working_dir: /home/deployment
    command: 
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        pip install flask
        flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Flask in your dockerfile:

```
RUN pip install Flask
```